# Select value based on current date being more than 1, 2 and 3 years from a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Good day,

I hope someone can assist me with a small line of code. I have build a sales rep commissions report, and for each item that a sales rep earns comm off, there is a date that the rep first got the item as new business, say for example, item A started 01/01/2018.

Their commission break down means that they get 7% for the first year after the start date (01/01/2018 < 1 year of current date), 5% if (01/01/2018 > 1 year of current date < 2 years of current date), 2.5% if (01/01/2018 > 2 years of current date < 3 years of current date).

I have written the select statement for the whole report, but I am battling to find any info on this.

I assume I would need a `CASE` statement, but I do I tell SQL to check if the current date is less than one year, or more than one year, but less thank 2 years, etc.

Really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: What about more than 3 year? And please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: Hi Salman A. From 3 years +, comm remains constant at 2.5%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use `CASE` like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(YEAR, 2, startdate) THEN 2.5
        WHEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= DATEADD(YEAR, 1, startdate) THEN 5.0
        ELSE 7.0
    END AS commission
```

Note that the cases are sorted.